# How to save value in foreach cycle?

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have foreach cycle in PHP. It is going trough json items, and for every item I have value that changes. I set my cycle to run every 20min.

I need my value to be saved and next time foreach runs for that item I need to assign at the beginning old value to variable so I can compare old and new value in foreach cycle.

here is the code:

```
// Parse results and extract data to display
foreach($json as $quote)
{
    //add before value
    $state1 = $state2;

    // assign object elements to vars
    $q_change  = $quote->c;
    $q_price   = $quote->l;
    $q_name    = $quote->t;
    $q_changep = $quote->cp;
    $q_symbol  = $quote->t;
    $q_ltrade  = $quote->lt;
    $q_exch    = $quote->e;

    $state2 = $q_change;

    $parametar = $q_change - $state1;

    // Define class based on change
    if ( $parametar < -0.3 ) { $chclass = "minus"; }
    else if ( $parametar > 0.3 ) { $chclass = "plus"; }
    else if ( $q_change < 0 ) { $chclass = "minus"; }
    else if ( $q_change > 0 ) { $chclass = "plus"; }
    else { $chclass = "zero"; $q_change = "0.00"; }
}
```

Any idea how that might work?

Comment: Perhaps session or a cookie?

Comment: Where does your data come from (source), is there a unique field you can relate to an entry? Give an example of your json

Comment: Post your code. What you have tried with expected result

Comment: Store the whole Array in SESSION and then `foreach` with new Array,

And when foreach finishes, reassign the new Array into same SESSION variable

Comment: i updated code, i get data from google financies

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the JSON on the file system to retrieve the values on subsequent runs:

```
$oldJsonFile = '/path/to/data.json';

if (is_file($file)) {
    $oldJson = file_get_contents($oldJsonFile);
}

// Do the work, and then store it back to the file system

file_put_contents($cacheFile, $newJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you are looking to do something like the following. Sessions will store your data for the next foreach execution.

```
session_start();
$previousData = $_SESSION['PreviousData'];

foreach($array as $key => $value){
    //... all your foreach calculations
    //end of foreach
}

$_SESSION['PreviousData'] = $thisData;
```

Alternatively you could store the data into a database, that's what they are for. Then you'll be free to do all kinds of interesting queries on past records etc.

Comment: how do I get my old value in foreach cycle with this sessions?

Comment: I'd recommend you read about sessions. Basically they are persistent variables, that will allow you to interact with data from previous script executions.

I've made a little edit to explain how to use the session.